# Full row-rank submatrix of full column-rank matrix over GF(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Let $M$ be an $m \times n$ tall ($m > n$) matrix over $\mbox{GF}(2)$. Let $M^{'}$ be an $r \times n$ submatrix of $M$ (where $r \leq m$) whose rows are randomly selected from $M$. Is it possible that the $M^{'}$ is full row-rank?

If it is, why?

If it is not, how about the case where $r < m$?

---

I have run some experiments on Matlab. In experiments, I first randomly generated $10^{6}$ matrices over $\mbox{GF}(2)$. Each matrix has $m = 288$ rows and $n = 216$ columns. Turn out they all have the rank of $216$. Then, I randomly generated $10^{6}$ matrices over GF(2). Each matrix has $m = 84$ rows and $n = 216$ columns. Turn out they all have the rank of $84$. So I am very confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a matrix can only have full row-rank if the number of rows it has is greater than or equal to the number of columns.  So, $M'$ can only have full row-rank if $r \leq n$.

That being said: because $M$ has full column-rank (according to your title), there is necessarily at least one $n \times n$ submatrix of $M$ that is invertible (full row and column rank), and every submatrix taken by choosing rows from the invertible submatrix will have full row rank.

As [I note here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399934/81360), if both matrices are randomly selected, then the probability that either fails to have full row-rank is smaller than $10^{-20}$, which in practice means that both matrices will "almost always" have full rank.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean I have to find out which $n \times n$ submatrices are invertible first, and then select $M{'}$ from these  $n \times n$ submatrices?

Comment: That wasn't quite what I was saying, since I'm really not sure what you're trying to do with your matrix.  Putting that aside for the moment: what you describe is not only way to get full-rank $r \times n$ submatrices, but it is true that every full-rank $r \times n$ submatrix **can** be attained in this way.

Comment: For sufficiently large matrices, it is notable that there is a very high probability that your randomly selected $m \times n$ matrix will have full-rank, and that your randomly selected $r \times n$ submatrix will also have full rank.  Are you interested in finding out what these probabilities are?

Comment: Yes. I have been reading a paper involving this problem. The authors said that $M$ is a full column-rank matrix, and they claimed that the $M'$ they arbitrarily selected from $M$ is a full row-rank submatrix. That confused me.

Is it because $M$ is over GF(2)?

If you are interested in this paper (maybe not), click [https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~tianhe/Papers/WEBee.pdf] and read section 4.

Comment: I'll take a look.  I suspect that the authors mean that $M'$ is *very likely* to be a full row-rank submatrix.  Notably, even if $M$ is a matrix over an infinite field like $\Bbb R$, it is possible to obtain an $m \times n$ matrix $M$ that has full row-rank for which most $r \times n$ matrices fail to have full row-rank.

Comment: Now that I have read the section you're talking about, it seems that they are just selecting $M'$ randomly, and then discuss what happens **if** $M'$ has full row-rank (page 5, right column, second paragraph: *"Given $M'$ is now a full row-rank matrix..."*).  Presumably, one could in practice select a random submatrix $M'$ and then check the rank.  If the low-probability event that $M'$ fails to have full rank occurs, we simply choose another random submatrix.

Comment: [I have asked my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399934/81360) about your post.  Hopefully we get a useful answer here.  If I find the time and energy I might answer it myself.

Comment: I got an answer to my question.  As I suspected, the probability that either matrix fails to have full row-rank is small enough that it can be considered negligible in practice.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is great!

Comment: @ShuMinYao You're welcome. If you're satisfied with my answer, please click the $\checkmark$ to the left of my post to "accept" the answer and mark your post as resolved.