# What is the probability that a matrix over $GF(2)$ fails to have full row-rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, finite-fields

This question relates to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399842/81360), which is ultimately concerned with [this paper](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~tianhe/Papers/WEBee.pdf).  I do my best to relay the relevant information here.

Within the linked paper, the authors seem to work under the assumption that if we select a random $288 \times 216$ matrix $M$ with entries in $GF(2)$ (the field with two elements), then there is a very high probability that $M$ has full column rank, and that a randomly selected $84 \times 216$ submatrix will have full column rank.  With that in mind, my question is the following:

> If a random $m \times n$ matrix $M$ over $GF(2)$ is selected (i.i.d. uniformly random $\{0,1\}$ entries), then what is the probability that $M$ will have maximal rank in the case where
>
> 1. $m = 288, n =216$
> 2. $m = 84, n = 216$

I am aware that there is a nice formula for this probability in the case where $M$ is square, but I'm not sure where to find (or how to derive off the top of my head) the corresponding probability for rectangular matrices.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564603)?

Comment: @metamorphy Great!  I tried searching but I guess I didn't have the right keywords there.  Thank you.  I'll post a quick answer for my specific case, hopefully before this question is marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [formula given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564603/81360), we find that the answer to 1 is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{216}(1 - 2^{i-1-288}) \approx 1 - 2\times 10^{-22},
$$
and the answer to 2 is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{84}(1 - 2^{i-1-216}) \approx 1 - 2\times 10^{-40}.
$$